# Sequelize-typescript - Parent select child's attributes

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I've a **Roles** belongTo **Appfunctions**, I would like to select Appfunctions's name as a  Role's attributes, but getting `Unknown column 'role->roles.appfunction.name' in 'field list'`

```
    const roleClause = {
      model: Role,
      required: false,
      attributes: ['canRead', 'canWrite', 'canDelete', [sequelize.col("appfunction.name"), "name"]],
      include: [],
    };
    clause.include.push(roleClause);
  
    const appFunctionsClause = {
      model: Appfunctions,
      required: true,
      attributes: [],
      include: [],
      where: {
        isActive: true
      }
    };
    roleClause.include.push(appFunctionsClause);
```

The code above will generate the query as below:

`'role->roles'.'appfunction.name' AS 'role.roles.name'`

This is not a valid query in mySQL.

Anyone know why `[sequelize.col("appfunction.name"), "name"]` not working in this case?

**The correct query should be `'role->roles->appfunction'.'name' AS 'role.roles.name'`**

Comment: Sounds vaguely similar to this issue here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7742